# Constexpr alternative to placement new to be able to leave objects in memory uninitialized?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to create a static container which has stack based memory and can hold N instances of T. Much alike `std::vector` I want currently unused memory to not contain initialized items of T. This is usually solved with placement new but that's not possible to use in constexpr.

**Using unions**
I found a trick that you can use a union for this as follows:

```
template <typename value_type>
union container_storage_type
{
    struct empty{};
    constexpr container_storage_type(): uninitialized{}{}
    constexpr container_storage_type(value_type v): value(v){}
    constexpr void set(value_type v)
    {
        *this = literal_container_storage_type{v};
    }

    empty uninitialized;
    value_type value;
};
```

This lets you store items uninitialized by setting the `empty` member and this works around the limitation that all members in constexpr have to be initialized.

Now the problem with this approach is that if `value_type`is a type that implements `operator=`, the [rule for unions says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union):

> If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment, or destructor), that function is deleted by default in the union and needs to be defined explicitly by the programmer.

This means that to be able to use this trick, I need to implement `operator=` in the union too, but how would that look?

```
constexpr container_storage_type& operator=(const container_storage_type& other)
{           
    value = other.value; //ATTEMPT #1
    //*this = container_storage_type(other.value);ATTEMPT #2

    return *this;
}
```

Attempt #1: This does not seem possible as the compiler complains that changing the active member of a union is simply disallowed in constant expressions.
Attempt #2: This works in the `set()` method from the previous snippet, as it doesn't change the active member per se, but reassigns the whole union. This trick seems unable to be used in the assignment operator however since that causes endless recursion...

Am I missing something here, or is this truly a dead end for using unions as a placement-new alternative in constexpr?

Are there other alternatives to placement new that I have completely missed?

https://godbolt.org/z/km0nTY Code that illustrates the problem

Comment: Why is not `std::array` sufficient for Your use case?

Comment: My use case is to implement a `static_vector<T, 10>` where 10 would be the capacity, and the vector itself keeps track of current count of entries. `std::array` alone cannot leave some entries with the constructor of `T` not run.

Comment: `std::array<optional<T>, 10>` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried the approach of making my `static_vector` be a wrapper of `std::array<std::optional<T>, 10>` along with a count, but `std::optional` is only partially constexpr enabled. for example, `operator=` or `.emplace` or any other way of setting the value that is not initialisation is not constexpr

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Please read the post before answering. placement-new (and reinterpret_cast for the matter) are not available in constexpr contexts

Comment: I see some conflicting goals here: First of all you want the array to create objects dynamically, i.e. at run-time. But you also want to use `constexpr` which seems to indicate you want object creation to happen at compile-time? Can you please elaborate on the actual problem you're trying to solve with a solution like that? What is the use-case?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The memory is meant to be statically allocated and known at compile time. The objects are meant to be initialized only when added to the container, which might be in runtime, or in compile time inside a constexpr factory function for example: `constexpr static_vector<T, 10> vec = make_vec(...);` where `make_vec` is a constexpr function.

Comment: @Tobias AFAIK, the only way to change the active member of a union where the member is not trivial is to use placement new.  The reason is that the constructor needs to be called on that storage to start it's lifetime and you can't do that without the placement new expression.

Comment: Does it *have* to be `constexpr`? Can't it be just plain `const`? And I still fail to see why you need a dynamic-size-but-fixed-capacity container that you can't actually add new elements to (the dynamic part). Why can't you use e.g. `constexpr auto vec = make_vec<int, 10>(...);` (where `make_vec` is something like `template<typename T, size_t N> constexpr std::array<T, N> make_vec(...) { ... }`)?

Comment: If you can live without compile-time assignment, your compile-time container may still be "write-once" for trivially destructible types using Andrzej's dual base class technique in https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/optional.hpp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++17, you can't.

The [current restrictions](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.20) on what you cannot do in constant expressions include:

> - an assignment expression ([expr.ass]) or invocation of an assignment operator ([class.copy.assign]) that would change the active member of a union;
> - a *new-expression*;

There really is no way around that.

---

In C++20, you will be able to, but probably not the way you think. The latter restriction is going to be relaxed in C++20 as a result of [P0784](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0784r4.html) to something like:

> - a *new-expression* (8.3.4), unless the selected allocation function is a replaceable global allocation function (21.6.2.1, 21.6.2.2);

That is, `new T` will become fine but `new (ptr) T` will still not be allowed. As part of making `std::vector` `constexpr`-friendly, we need to be able to manage "raw" memory - but we still can't actually manage truly *raw* memory. Everything still has to be typed. Dealing with raw bytes is not going to work.

But `std::allocator` doesn't *entirely* deal in raw bytes. `allocate(n)` gives you a `T*` and `construct` takes a `T*` as a location and a bunch of arguments and creates a new object at that location. You may be wondering at this point how this is any different from placement new - and the only difference is that sticking with `std::allocator`, we stay in the land of `T*` - but placement new uses `void*`. That distinction turns out to be critical.

Unfortunately, this has the interesting consequence of your `constexpr` version "allocates" memory (but it allocates compiler memory, which will get elevated to static storage as necessary - so this does what you want) - but your pure runtime version surely does not want to allocate memory, indeed the whole point would be that it does not. To that end, you will have to use `is_constant_evaluated()` to switch between the allocating at constant evaluation time and non-allocating at runtime. This is admittedly not beautiful, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer. Too bad c++ doesn't provide a clean way to do this but at least it will be at all possible in c++20.

Comment: This deserves to be "answer of the month".

Answer (score -3):

Your storage can look something like this:

```
// For trivial objects
using data_t = const array<remove_const_t<T>, Capacity>>;
alignas(alignof(T)) data_t data_{};
// For non-trivial objects
alignas(alignof(T)) aligned_storage_t<T> data_[Capacity]{};
```

This will allow you to create a `const` array of *non*-`const` objects. Then constructing objects will look something like this:

```
// Not real code, for trivial objects
data_[idx] = T(forward<Args>(args)...);
// For non-trivial objects
new (end()) T(forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Placement new is mandatory here. You will be able to have the storage at compile-time, but you cannot **construct** it at compile-time for non-trivial objects.

You will also need to take into account whether or not your container is zero-sized, etc. I suggest you look at existing implementations for fixed sized vectors and there are even some proposals for `constexpr` fixed sized vectors like [p0843r1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0843r1.html).

Comment: I am not sure I understand, how will that const array of non-const objects not mean that the constructor of T is called on every item initially?

Comment: If you make an `array<remove_const_t<T>, Capacity>>` it's going to initialize the members which the OP doesn't want

Comment: @Tobias You said that you want to be able to use it at runtime. For non-trivial objects, you will need to use non-constexpr emplace_back which will use placement new.

Comment: @NathanOliver You can't have your cake and eat it too. It's possible to have uninitialized storage at compile time, but you can't also construct those objects (using placement new) at compile-time. My code is only showing the case for *trivial* objects.

Comment: But `data_t data_{}` does initialize trivial objects since `array` is an aggregate.  They will all be zero initialized.

Comment: @user10586264 as described in my post, you can _almost_ do what i want using unions, and it works leaving the items uninitialized in compile time, with exception for the assignment operator problem